# How to create a filter form for a (class based) generic object list in Django?

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.3's class based generic view to display a list of images, but I want to add a filter that enables the user to narrow down the displayed results.

My current approach works, but feels quite hackish:

```
class ImageFilterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image

class ImageListView(ListView):
    model = Image

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Image.objects.select_related()  
        for item in self.request.GET:
            key, value = item, self.request.GET.getlist(item)
            # ... Filtering here ...
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ImageListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter_form'] = ImageFilterForm(self.request.GET)
        return context
```

Are there better means to add custom filtering to a generic view?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I use the same approach, but generic, using a mixin:

```
class FilterMixin(object):

    def get_queryset_filters(self):
        filters = {}
        for item in self.allowed_filters:
            if item in self.request.GET:
                 filters[self.allowed_filters[item]] = self.request.GET[item]
        return filters

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(FilterMixin, self).get_queryset()\
              .filter(**self.get_queryset_filters())


class ImageListView(FilterMixin, ListView):

    allowed_filters = {
        'name': 'name',
        'tag': 'tag__name',
    }

    # no need to override get_queryset
```

This allows to specify a list of accepted filters, and they don't need to correspond to the actual `.filter()` keywords. You can then expand it to support more complex filtering (split by comma when doing an `__in` or `__range` filter is an easy example)

Comment: I just found the [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) app and combined it with your mixin. I think that's clean enough for me ;-) Thanks!

Comment: I also used django-filter and in combination with get_queryset() method above and it works nicely. fyi, filter.qs is the attribute that returns the filtered queryset from a filterset object (part of the django-filter app)

Comment: To use this feature for forms.DateField, how i can do?

Comment: Is this still a valid answer?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) it easy solution for filtering data in view

Comment: looks promising, however misses AJAX!