# Django: Search form in Class Based ListView

Tags: django, forms, listview, django-class-based-views

I am trying to realize a `Class Based ListView` which displays a selection of a table set. If the site is requested the first time, the dataset should be displayed. I would prefer a POST submission, but GET is also fine.

That is a problem, which was easy to handle with `function based views`, however with class based views I have a hard time to get my head around.

My problem is that I get a various number of error, which are caused by my limited understanding of the classed based views. I have read various documentations and I understand views for direct query requests, but as soon as I would like to add a form to the query statement, I run into different error. For the code below, I receive an `ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value`.

**What would be the best practise work flow for a class based ListView depending on form entries (otherwise selecting the whole database)?**

This is my sample code:

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%name' % {'name': self.name}

    @staticmethod
    def get_queryset(params):

        date_created = params.get('date_created')
        keyword = params.get('keyword')
        qset = Q(pk__gt = 0)
        if keyword:
            qset &= Q(title__icontains = keyword)
        if date_created:
            qset &= Q(date_created__gte = date_created)
        return qset
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileSearchForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileList(ListView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileSearchForm
    context_object_name = 'profiles'
    template_name = 'pages/profile/list_profiles.html'
    profiles = []


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.show_results = False
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        form = form_class(self.request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            self.show_results = True
            self.profiles = Profile.objects.filter(name__icontains=form.cleaned_data['name'])
        else:
            self.profiles = Profile.objects.all()
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(object_list=self.object_list, form=form))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if not self.profiles:
            self.profiles = Profile.objects.all()
        context.update({
            'profiles': self.profiles
        })
        return context
```

Below I added the FBV which does the job. **How can I translate this functionality into a CBV?**
It seems to be so simple in function based views, but not in class based views.

```
def list_profiles(request):
    form_class = ProfileSearchForm
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'pages/profile/list_profiles.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    form = form_class(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        profile_list = model.objects.filter(name__icontains=form.cleaned_data['name'])
    else:
        profile_list = model.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(profile_list, 10) # Show 10 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        profiles = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        profiles = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        profiles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response(template_name, 
            {'form': form, 'profiles': suppliers,}, 
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Question, are you trying to display a value from a queryset based on form submission?

Comment: Have a look at this generic mixin approach:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011773/how-to-create-a-filter-form-for-a-class-based-generic-object-list-in-django

Comment: Give up on sticking with class-based views. Do it with function-based views to gain on speed and readability. You'd really not want to maintain this code after, lets say a year!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django class based view ListView with form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406553/django-class-based-view-listview-with-form)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think your goal is trying to filter queryset based on form submission, if so, by using GET :

```
class ProfileSearchView(ListView)
    template_name = '/your/template.html'
    model = Person

    def get_queryset(self):
        name = self.kwargs.get('name', '')
        object_list = self.model.objects.all()
        if name:
            object_list = object_list.filter(name__icontains=name)
        return object_list
```

Then all you need to do is write a `get` method to render template and context.

Maybe not the best approach. By using the code above, you no need define a Django form.

Here's how it works : Class based views separates its way to render template, to process form  and so on. Like, `get` handles GET response, `post` handles POST response, `get_queryset` and `get_object` is self explanatory, and so on. The easy way to know what's method available, fire up a shell and type :

`from django.views.generic import ListView` if you want to know about `ListView`

and then type `dir(ListView)`. There you can see all the method defined and go visit the source code to understand it. The `get_queryset` method used to get a queryset. Why not just  define it like this, it works too :

```
class FooView(ListView):
    template_name = 'foo.html'
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()  # or anything
```

We can do it like above, but we can't do dynamic filtering by using that approach. By using `get_queryset` we can do dynamic filtering, using any data/value/information we have, it means we also can use `name` parameter that is sent by `GET`, and it's available on `kwargs`, or in this case, on `self.kwargs["some_key"]` where `some_key` is any parameter you specified

Comment: instead of using the try you could use get with a default value, i think it helps with readability. `name = self.kargs.get('name', None)` and then `if name: # do some stuff`

Comment: how we can do the same if we have to query in multiple models and send the results?

Answer (score 16):

Well, I think that leaving validation to form is nice idea. Maybe not worth it in this particular case, because it is very simple form - but for sure with more complicated one (and maybe yours will grow also), so I would do something like:

```
class ProfileList(ListView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileSearchForm
    context_object_name = 'profiles'
    template_name = 'pages/profile/list_profiles.html'
    profiles = []


    def get_queryset(self):
        form = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            return Profile.objects.filter(name__icontains=form.cleaned_data['name'])
        return Profile.objects.all()
```

Comment: i got an error that form_class is not defined, how to fix?

Comment: Vic Nicethemer, you can define it

Comment: @VicNicethemer It should be form = self.form_class(self.request.GET).

Answer (score 16):

This is similar to @jasisz 's approach, but simpler.

```
class ProfileList(ListView):
    template_name = 'your_template.html'
    model = Profile

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.none()
        return object_list
```

Then all you have to do on the html template is:

```
<form method='GET'>
  <input type='text' name='q' value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
  <input class="button" type='submit' value="Search Profile">
</form>
```

Comment: can you please guide me with url here,

Answer (score 4):

This has been explained nicely on the generic views topic here [Dynamic filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering).

You can do filtering through `GET`, I don't think you can use `POST` method for this as `ListView` is not inherited from edit mixings.

What you can do is:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
                (r'^search/(\w+)/$', ProfileSearchListView.as_view()),
              )
```

views.py

```
class ProfileSearchListView(ListView):
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'profiles'
    template_name = 'pages/profile/list_profiles.html'
    profiles = []

    def get_queryset(self):
         if len(self.args) > 0:
               return Profile.objects.filter(name__icontains=self.args[0])
         else:
               return Profile.objects.filter()
```

Comment: Working link for dynamic filtering : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error you are getting is because your form doesn't require the name field. So, although the form is valid, the cleaned_data for your `name` field is empty.

These could be the problematic lines:

```
if form.is_valid():
    self.show_results = True
    self.profiles = Profile.objects.filter(name__icontains=form.cleaned_data['name'])
```

If I were you, I would try changing the line:

```
self.profiles = Profile.objects.filter(name__icontains=form.cleaned_data['name'])
```

to this:

```
self.profiles = Profile.objects.none()
```

If you stop receiving errors (and your template receives an empty `object_list`), the problem you have is what I said before: name field not required.

Let us know if this doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Search on all fields in model

```
class SearchListView(ItemsListView):

# Display a Model List page filtered by the search query.

def get_queryset(self):
    fields = [m.name for m in super(SearchListView, self).model._meta.fields]
    result = super(SearchListView, self).get_queryset()
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        result = result.filter(
            reduce(lambda x, y: x | Q(**{"{}__icontains".format(y): query}), fields, Q())
        )
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query_name = self.request.GET.get('query', '')
    object_list = Product.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query_name) 
    )
    return object_list

<form action="" method="GET">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search keyword">
       <i class="ti-search"></i>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).